# No image from inflater with custom image format

Tags: android, layout-inflater

I have this custom image format that `BitmapFactory` is unable to read. So I have written a derivate `Resources` class which decodes my image format into drawables. I return this custom Resources instance in `Activity.getResources()`.

This solution works well for in-code resource reading, and I see images decoded like this.

But when I declare an image resource in layout files, all I get is a debug message in logcat saying

> skia     --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

As if `LayoutInflater` doesn't even call `activity.getResources()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging it turns out that this is not possible to be done in this way.

TextView class constructor will call `Resources.loadDrawable(TypedValue value, int id)` which is private. `loadDrawable` only calls `Resources.getCachedDrawable(LongSparseArray<WeakReference<ConstantState>> drawableCache, long key)`, which is again private.

How do Google's programmers achieve this kind of show-stoppers is beyond my comprehension. It takes extremely meticulous planning to give a programmer hope and then squash them later on with a well-aimed private, static or whatever. /rant